# How to find colletion of Forms?

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0

i am developing an application in which there are many form  i want to get a colletion of all these forms which are in open or hide state. how would i implement this.

Answer (score 1):

This will help you get all forms opened by the application

```
FormCollection col = Application.OpenForms;
```

Comment: But here i want the Open and not opened forms also.

Answer (score 1):

In .net 4.0 there is still a defect with Application.OpenForms. The form will be removed from the list of forms when changing ShowInTaskbar property. Use Application.OpenForms if you are sure that they do not change ShowInTaskbar. Otherwise think about managing your own OpenForms collection